# My Custom UIView is not removed from SuperView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have one **PopUpView** which I add to a **ViewController**.

I have created a delegate Method **didTapOnOKPopUp()** so that when I click on Ok Button in the PopUpView, It should remove from the ViewController which using it's delegate.

Here is the code for **PopUpView.Swift**

```
protocol PopUpViewDelegate: class {
    func didTapOnOKPopUp()
}


class PopUpView: UIView {
weak var delegate : PopUpViewDelegate?

@IBAction func btnOkPopUpTap(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        delegate?.didTapOnOKPopUp()
    }
}
```

Here is the code for **ForgotPasswordViewController** where I am using delegate method.

```
class ForgotPasswordViewController: UIViewController, PopUpViewDelegate {

// I have created an Instance for the PopUpView and assign Delegate also.

func popUpInstance() -> UIView {
        let popUpView = UINib(nibName: "PopUpView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as! PopUpView
        popUpView.delegate = self
        return popUpView
    }
// Here I am adding my view as Subview. It's added successfully.
@IBAction func btnSendTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.view.addSubview(self.popUpInstance())
    }
```

[image: It's added successfully]

```
// But when I tapping on OK Button. My PopUpView is not removing from it's View Controller. 

func didTapOnOKPopUp() {

        self.popUpInstance().removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37271823/7755028) but No Success! Please Help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each call to `popupinstance()` creates a new `PopUp` View.

You can either create a reference to the created pop up :

```
private var displayedPopUp: UIView?
@IBAction func btnSendTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
    displayedPopUp = self.popUpInstance()
    self.view.addSubview(displayedPopUp)
}


func didTapOnOKPopUp() {
    self.displayedPopUp?.removeFromSuperview()
    displayedPopUp = nil
}
```

But I think in your case using a `lazy var` is better :

replace

```
func popUpInstance() -> UIView {
        let popUpView = UINib(nibName: "PopUpView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as! PopUpView
        popUpView.delegate = self
        return popUpView
    }
```

by :

```
lazy var popUpInstance : UIView =  {
        let popUpView = UINib(nibName: "PopUpView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as! PopUpView
        popUpView.delegate = self
        return popUpView
    }()
```

Now every call to `popUpInstance` will return the same instance of your popUp

Comment: Nice and Simple! Thanks Mate. :)

Answer (score 4):

Every time you call `.popUpInstance()`, it creates a brand new `PopupView` instance, thus causing you to lose the reference to the previously created and added one in the view hierarchy.

Define `popUpView` as an instance variable and you should be good to go:

```
class ForgotPasswordViewController: UIViewController, PopUpViewDelegate {

  private lazy var popupView: PopUpView = {
    let popUpView = UINib(nibName: "PopUpView", bundle: nil)
      .instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)
      .first as! PopUpView

     popUpView.delegate = self
     return popUpView
  }()

  @IBAction func btnSendTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.view.addSubview(self.popupView)
  }

  func didTapOnOKPopUp() {
    self.popupView.removeFromSuperview()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time! It solved my issue. Glad that you helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call the function popUpInstance you create another instance of PopUpView, when you do so your delegate is not relevant.

you can do this part of the code in some ways:

1. create the popUpInstance() function and save the instance as a class parameter
2. make a class parameter like this

   ```
   private lazy var popupView: PopUpView = {
       let popUpView = UINib(nibName: "PopUpView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as! PopUpView
       popUpView.delegate = self
       return popUpView 
   }()
   ```